# How to join 2 tables and order them?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `_divions` and `_employee`. In `_employee` there's a column `division` which is `id_division` in the table `_division`. I need to order them by the `_division` order first.

This table has a column `order`. I have tried this SQL statement, but it doesn't do much:

```
SELECT
    e . *
FROM
    `_employee` AS  `e`
JOIN
    `_division` AS d
ORDER BY
    d.order,
    e.division,
    e.order
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing `ON` clause. Try this

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM _employee AS e 
JOIN _division AS d ON d.id_division = e.division
 //                ^^^^  Missing
ORDER BY e.order
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query may help.  (Assuming there are divisions with no employees)

```
    with employee as
(
 select 'NISHA' ENAME, '10' EDIV FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT 'ABC' ENAME, '10' EDIV FROM DUAL 
 UNION
 SELECT 'DEF' ENAME, '15' EDIV FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT 'GHI' ENAME, '20' EDIV FROM DUAL
),
DIVISION AS
(
  SELECT '10' DIV_ID, 'INFO-TECH' DIV_DESC FROM DUAL 
  UNION
  SELECT '15' DIV_ID, 'HUMAN RESOURCES' DIV_DESC FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT '20' DIV_ID, 'SALES' DIV_DESC FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT '25' DIV_ID, 'RESEARCH' DIV_DESC FROM DUAL
)
  SELECT *
  FROM EMPLOYEE, DIVISION WHERE
  employee.EDIV (+) = DIVISION.DIV_ID 
  ORDER BY DIV_DESC, ENAME
```

If all employees would definitely have a division,then use           employee.EDIV = DIVISION.DIV_ID instead of employee.EDIV (+) = DIVISION.DIV_ID